# How to insert and update bulk data From one DB to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

There are two DBs on different servers. I want to run a procedure once a day so that I can get updated records. If it already exists then it should update, else insert a new row.

So far I did it like this:

```
if not exists (Select emp_id  From DB1.dbo.Emp_Master where emp_code = (Select pk_emp_code From DB2)
    Begin
    INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.Emp_Master(emp_code,emp_name,emp_dept ,emp_desg ,emp_mob ,email_id,emp_dob,emp_doj)
    Select pk_emp_code,first_name+ '' +last_name,dept.dept_desc,
     desg.desig_desc,office_phone,email,REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(dob AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-') ,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(doj AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-')
    From DB2
        Select 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN


    UPDATE DB1.dbo.Emp_Master SET emp_name=first_name+ '' + last_name,emp_dept=dept.dept_desc,emp_desg=desg.desig_desc,
    email_id=email,emp_mob=office_phone,emp_dob=REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(dob AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-'),
    emp_doj=REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(doj AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-') 
    FROM [DB2]
    where emp_code =pk_emp_code
    Select 2
    END
```

I am getting error

> SubQuery return more than one value

What's gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this part that returns the error (inside your IF NOT EXISTS):

```
Select emp_id  From DB1.dbo.Emp_Master where emp_code = (Select pk_emp_code From DB2)
```

There is no correlation between the inner and outer query. A possible rewrite is along these lines:

```
Select emp_id  From DB1.dbo.Emp_Master where emp_code IN (Select pk_emp_code From DB2)
```

Moreover, the check you're doing at the very beginning of your code will skip inserting all the rows if any of them matches.

I suppose that what you want to do here is an upsert (if matched updated, if not matched insert). You can do it with the `MERGE` statement or with something like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#updatedRows') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #updatedRows;

CREATE TABLE #updatedRows (
    emp_code int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

UPDATE DB1.dbo.Emp_Master 
SET emp_name = first_name+ '' + last_name,
    emp_dept = dept.dept_desc,
    emp_desg = desg.desig_desc,
    email_id = email,
    emp_mob = office_phone,
    emp_dob = REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(dob AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-'),
    emp_doj = REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(doj AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-') 
OUTPUT INSERTED.emp_code INTO #updatedRows
FROM [DB2]
WHERE emp_code = pk_emp_code;


INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.Emp_Master(
    emp_code,
    emp_name,
    emp_dept,
    emp_desg,
    emp_mob,
    email_id,
    emp_dob,
    emp_doj
)
SELECT 
    pk_emp_code,
    first_name + '' + last_name,
    dept.dept_desc,
    desg.desig_desc,
    office_phone,
    email,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(dob AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-') ,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(doj AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-')
FROM DB2
WHERE pk_emp_code NOT IN (
    SELECT emp_code
    FROM #updatedRows
);
```